# Do we need to add a new [webhook] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

WebHooks are an established technology in GIS.

> A [webhook](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/create-and-manage-webhooks.htm) is a mechanism that allows an application to provide
> other applications with event-driven information.
>
> You can configure your webhooks to automatically notify you when
> events associated with your items, groups, and users occur. Once a
> webhook is triggered, an HTTP request is made to a unique,
> user-defined payload URL to provide information regarding the event.

Do we need to add a new [webhook](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webhook) tag?

Answer (score 5):

Tags can be created when questions are asked. Since the tag doesn't exist yet it appears it hasn't been needed yet.

If you are asking a question and do not have the required reputation to create the tag, you can flag it and ask a moderator to add the tag, or ask here in meta, or ask in chat.

Answer (score 3):

I think it may be premature to create a [webhook](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/webhook) tag because the term has never been used in a question, and has only ever been used twice in an answer ([recently in Aug 2020 and two years ago in Sep 2018](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=webhook)).

There is no rule for how frequently a term needs to be used here before it becomes tag worthy but the rule of thumb that I use on when to create a new tag is whether it is likely to be used a few hundred times over the next few years.